# Warning: a not-numberic value encountered PHP 7.1

Tags: php7

Есть сайт на Joomla.
Есть проблема с библиотекой которая выводит меню.
На версии PHP 7.0 всё хорошо, перешёл на версию 7.1 или 7.2 и стал руинить пункты меню и выдавать сообщение: warning: a not-numberic value encountered в php файле меню.
Начал читать и понял что в версии PHP 7.1 ввели новые правила для числовых операторов.
Но смотря на этот код я так и не разобрался в чём проблема.

```
function beginMenuItems1($pid = 0, $level = 0, $return = false)
    {
        $cols = $pid && $this->getParam('megamenu') && isset($this->items[$pid]->cols) && $this->items[$pid]->cols ? $this->items[$pid]->cols : 1;
        $width = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get('width', 0);
        if (!$width) {
            for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
                $colw = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get('colw' . ($col + 1), 0);
                if (!$colw) $colw = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get('colw', $this->getParam('mega-colwidth', 200));
                if (is_null($colw) || !is_numeric($colw)) $colw = 200;
                $width += $colw;
            }
        }
        $style = $width ? " style=\"width: {$width}px;\"" : "";
        $right = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get('right') ? 'right' : '';
        $data = "<span class=\"dropdown-spacer\"></span><div class=\"dropdown cols$cols $right\" $style>\n";
        if ($return)
            return $data;
        else
            echo $data;
    }
```

Точное место ошибки это вот этот if, а точнее результат сложения во второй строке if.

```
if (is_null($colw) || !is_numeric($colw)) $colw = 200;
            $width += $colw;
```

Если убрать последний if который проверяет на ноль или не число, то меню становится нормальным и ошибок нет. Но мне хотелось бы понять как это исправить правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему приведя строку 'width' к числу через int.
Было:

```
$width = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get('width', 0);
```

Стало:

```
$width = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get((int)'width', 0);
```

Не понимаю как это работает, там слово 'width' в одиночных кавычках и зачем его приводить к числовому значению?

Comment: написав `(int)` перед строкой вы его перевели в цифру 0, теперь ваш код выглядит так: `$width = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get(0, 0);` приводить тип нужно к полученному результату `$width = (int) $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get('width', 0);`

Comment: @Alpha всё верно, спасибо, это работает.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть проверка: `if (!$width)` тогда вы делаете цикл for, и что-то мне подсказывает что переменная `$width` не цифра, скорее всего проблема именно в этом

Comment: Есть идеи как исправить?)

Comment: @velyar так а что находится в переменной то?

Comment: $width = $this->items[$pid]->megaparams->get('width', 0); Так вот же вроде что записывается в переменную:)

Comment: @Alpha Спасибо, вроде решил.

Comment: @velyar так, а откуда я могу знать какое значение содержит переменная? Чтобы помочь вам.